# getting type error in Haskell using my code

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, incompatibletypeerror

So I've got an assignment to 
Write a function

```
search_string:: String -> String -> Integer
search_string mainstring substring = ...
```

that takes two string arguments mainstring and substring and examines if substring occurs as a substring of mainstring. If so, the function should compute the position in mainstring where substring starts. If substring occurs multiple times it is the position of the first occurrence that should be computed. If substring does not occur in mainstring the function should compute `-1`.

So this is my code so far:

```
search_string main sub = if sub == take (length sub) main then 0 else search_string_aux main sub 1
search_string_aux main sub n = if sub == search_string (drop n main) sub then n else search_string_aux main sub (n+1)
```

when I try to load it haskell tells me:

```
Labb4hs:11:79:
  Couldn't match expected type '[a0]' with actual type 'Int'
  In the expression : n 
  In the expression:
   If sub == search_string (drop n main) sub then n
   else search_string_aux main sub (n+1)
  In an equation for `search_string_aux':
   search_string_aux main sub n = if sub == search_string (drop n main) sub then n 
   else search_string_aux main sub (n+1)
```

So it seems Haskell thinks that n should be a `[a0] =(string ???)` with actual type `Int`, and I want to make `n` an `Int` always so I don't get why haskell thinks it's a `[a0]`. Would gladly appreciate some help since I'm new to Haskell and programming in general and I have no clue whatsoever on how to fix it.

Comment: You have an *assignment* to use -1 for "no match"? This function should give a `Maybe Integer`. This is not C.

Comment: yeah I have no idea why they want the function to return -1 if it doesn't match but they do so not much more to it. However I got it to work so no worries my :)

Comment: This is highly suspect...

Answer (score 3):

1. Try adding a type signature to `search_string_aux`. This will make the error a bit easier to find.
2. `if sub == search_string` ...but wait, doesn't `search_string` return `Integer`? Yet `sub` is meant to be `String`... Something is not right here.

Comment: you got a good point there I can't have `sub == search_strig ..` I want it to always check some version of main

Comment: I got it to work!!! :D wiii so happy atm thx for noticing that error cause I was soooo blind to it have been working on the code for a long time makes you not see certain things